# Pandas Dataframe to Network graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, pyvis

I have some CSV files with more than 100 lines, like this table,
[image: image 1].

I am trying to create a graph from A to B, C, and D with the weight edge distance.

[image: Final output]

I am right now using pyvis, but the problem is the edge lengths are all the same.

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML
from pyvis.network import Network 

df = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv')
got_net = Network(notebook=True, cdn_resources='in_line')

sources = df['from']
targets = df['to']
weights = df['weight']
edge_data = zip(sources, targets, weights)

for e in edge_data:
    src = e[0]
    dst = e[1]
    w = e[2]

    got_net.add_node(src, src, title=src)
    got_net.add_node(dst, dst, title=dst)
    got_net.add_edge(src, dst, label = "weight")


neighbor_map = got_net.get_adj_list()  

for node in got_net.nodes:
    node['title'] += ' Neighbors:' + ''.join(neighbor_map[node['id']])
    node['value'] = len(neighbor_map[node['id']])

got_net.save_graph('graph.html')
display(HTML("graph.html"))
```

Comment: Please share your attempt and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

## Don't forget to set the 'physics engine' of the network graph, and also use the `value` (not `label`) parameter when setting the weights of the edges

For example, consider a network visualization showing the frequency of bigrams in a famous piece of English literature, say Shakespeare's ["To be or not to be" soliloquy](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/56965/speech-to-be-or-not-to-be-that-is-the-question) from *Hamlet*:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import re

hamlet_speech = # [See link above]

shakespeare_letters = re.sub("[',.;:\-\—?\n ]", "", hamlet_speech.upper())

bigrams = [
    shakespeare_letters[i : i + 2]
    for i in range(len(shakespeare_letters) - 1)
]

freqs = defaultdict(int)

for xy in bigrams:
    freqs[xy] += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[*xy] + [w] for xy, w in freqs.items()], columns=["from", "to", "weight"]
)
df.sort_values(by="weight", inplace=True, ascending=False)
df = df[df.weight > 3]
df
```

gives:

```
    from to  weight
10     T  H      53
16     H  E      33
35     N  D      19
0      T  O      18
55     O  F      17
..   ... ..     ...
226    R  D       4
241    L  L       4
21     I  O       4
8      T  T       4
166    P  A       4

[99 rows x 3 columns]
```

> **Note**: *I've included only the most frequent (occurrence > 3) pairs of subsequent letters for the sake of simplifying this example.*

Unsurprisingly, the most principal results are:

- **"TH" (e.g., as in "the"...) is the most common bigram,**
- **followed by "HE" (also, as in, "the"...).**

---

Let's see how `pyvis` visually represents this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML
from pyvis.network import Network

got_net = Network(
    notebook=True,
    cdn_resources="remote",
    height="500px",
    width="100%",
    bgcolor="white",
    font_color="red",
)

# set the physics layout of the network
got_net.repulsion()
got_data = df

sources = got_data["from"]
targets = got_data["to"]
weights = got_data["weight"]

edge_data = zip(sources, targets, weights)

for e in edge_data:
    src = e[0]
    dst = e[1]
    w = e[2]

    got_net.add_node(src, src, title=src)
    got_net.add_node(dst, dst, title=dst)
    got_net.add_edge(src, dst, value=w)

neighbor_map = got_net.get_adj_list()

# add neighbor data to node hover data
for node in got_net.nodes:
    node["title"] += "\nNeighbors:\n"
    neighbor_distances = {}
    for neighbor in neighbor_map[node["id"]]:
        bigram = node["id"] + neighbor
        dist = freqs[bigram]
        neighbor_distances[neighbor] = dist
    for n, d in sorted(
        neighbor_distances.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True
    ):
        node["title"] += f"{n}: {d}\n"
    node["value"] = len(neighbor_map[node["id"]])

got_net.show("network.html")
```

[image: Example of pyvis network HTML interactive graph in jupyter notebook]

Clearly, a critical consideration with such a type of "network" visualization is the reality that individual nodes can be simultaneously a place of "from" *and* "to". And thus, when visualizing the "weight" of any connection between two individual nodes, it must be taken into consideration the weight in *both* directions. This can become obviously quite complex pretty quickly as the number of nodes and possible pairwise paths permutationally increase.

Nonetheless `pyvis` handles this excellently, by making the network interactive and also by visually representing the strength, if you will, (i.e., the `weight`) of node interconnections by both their overall placement in the network relative to other nodes but also the *width* of their edges.